# In Tikz, how can I use the fill option on top of a graphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, fill

In tikzpicture, within an axis environment I am uploading a figure with

```
\addplot graphics[xmin=0,ymin=-.15,xmax=10,ymax=1.1] {figure.png};
```

On top of this figure I can draw two lines

```
\addplot [name path=line1,color=red] table[row sep=crcr]{...data1...};
\addplot [name path=line3,color=red] table[row sep=crcr]{...data2...};
```

Now I would normally add a uniform filling between `line1` and `line2` with

```
\addplot[blue] fill between[of=line1 and line2];
```

However this does not work as it is overlapped by the graphics added previously. Is there a way to have the filling overlapping the graphics? How else can I do it?

A MWE would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=4,ymax=16]
\addplot [name path=line1,color=red, line width=1.5pt] 
  table[row sep=crcr]{%    
0   0\\
1   1\\
2   4\\
3   9\\
4   16\\
};
\addplot graphics[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=4,ymax=16] {figure.png};
\addplot [name path=line2,color=blue, line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0                   0\\
1                   1\\
2                   2\\
3                   3\\
4                   4\\
};
\addplot[olive] fill between[of=line1 and line2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The first thing you should do is adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a look at the `on layer` key (section 4.27.3 * Changing the Layer of Graphical Elements* in the manual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to add `on layer=axis background` in the options of `addplot`. The following code would work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=4,ymax=16]
\addplot [name path=line1,color=red, line width=1.5pt] 
  table[row sep=crcr]{%    
0   0\\
1   1\\
2   4\\
3   9\\
4   16\\
};
\addplot[on layer=axis background] graphics[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=4,ymax=16] {figure.png};
\addplot [name path=line2,color=blue, line width=1.5pt]    
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0                   0\\
1                   1\\
2                   2\\
3                   3\\
4                   4\\
};
\addplot[olive] fill between[of=line1 and line2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help to use example-image and post a picture.